# Facebook api not working in subdirectories

Tags: php, facebook

Trying to plug in the new login api from a test script in a subdirectory of my site, and seeing that when I call getUser() I'm getting back a Facebook user id of 0.

When I move the same script into my domain root, I get what I expect - my FB uid.

This obviously puts me at a serious disadvantage as far as testing goes. Is it possible to use the new api from a subdirectory, and if so, what do I need to do?

Comment: Is your app setting on facebook have domain root as Site URL? I guess that can be causing a problem for subdirectory.

Comment: I checked that, and it is. For kicks I added the subdirectory and it worked, even though the app settings don't show the subdirectory. Who knows. At least it's working now.